# Htaccess rule that does not work tried my best but

Tags: mod-rewrite, redirect

Hello
I would like to redirect some old urls to new ones without success, here are the old ones : 
http://www.exemple.com/keywords.php?keyword=KEYWORD
http://www.exemple.com/search/qs.html?qsvd=oc&searchkey=KEYWORD

I would like them to be : 
http://www.exemple.com/Recherche.html?searchword=KEYWORD

Here is what i tried :

RewriteRule ^/?keywords.php?keyword=(.*) /Recherche.html?searchword=$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^/?search/qs.html?qsvd=oc&searchkey=(.*) /Recherche.html?searchword=$1 [R=301,L]

No success. I have tried other rewriting methods as well...now i am a bit stuck because i do not have any precise idea on the rule to insert. 
Any help would be appreciated 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^keyword=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^/keywords.php$ /Recherche.html?searchword=%1 [R=301,L]
```

Note the use of %1 to access the patter from the rewrite cond rather than $1 to access the pattern from the rule...

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use RewriteCond to get at the information in the query string.